# Getting notified if the data is loaded when the data is in a computed field

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a Vue project with vuetify, and i want to use the loading functionality.
The project is set up so the items are loaded with a computed field. 
How do i now manipulate the 'loading' property, turning it of when its loaded?

I tried attaching the items async fetching the data with a non-computed field. But the v-data-table is turned into a component and i'm not succeeding.

```
     <data-table 
      :title="title" 
      :headers="headers"
      :items="allUsers"
      :loading="loading"
      @editItem="onEdit"
      @deleteItem="onDelete" >
    </data-table>
```

The allUsers property is computed
Right now the loaded property is also computed putting a .length on the allusers. This only works if there are users ... if none it keeps spinning.

```
computed: {
    allUsers () {
      return this.$store.getters['users/users']
    },
    loading(){
       return this.$store.getters['users/users'] != null;
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you load users into your store within an action, you should also set some state for *loading*.

For example (simplified, no module)

```js
const store = {
  state: {
    users: [],
    loading: false
  },
  mutations: {
    setUsers (state, users) {
      state.users = users
    },
    isLoading (state) {
      state.loading = true
    },
    loadingComplete (state) {
      state.loading = false
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async loadUsers ({ commit }) {
      commit('isLoading') // set loading state
      commit('setUsers', await fetchUserDataFromSomwhere())
      commit('loadingComplete')
    }
  }
}
```

Now your components can subscribe to the `loading` state

```js
computed: {
  loading () {
    return this.$store.state.loading // or use mapState / mapGetters / whatever
  },
  allUsers () {
    return this.$store.state.users
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything was there.
It works. The missing info for me was i had to alter the state ( add a property )
And manipulate it from the store. I was looking at it from the page (using nuxt)